# Segmentation faults in hardened ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, grsec

I am running Ubuntu Linux 14.04 webserver and it has grsec patch applied.
Absolutely randomly websites become unaccessible and i seeing segmentation faults in dmesg.
May i temporary or permanently disable grsec to investigate further server's stability when running without grsec ?

```
grsec: Segmentation fault occurred at 000003e80000113c in /usr/sbin/apache2[apache2:4412] uid/euid:1000/1000 gid/egid:1000/1000, parent /usr/sbin/apache2[apache2:4286] uid/euid:0/0 gid/egid:0/0
grsec: From 127.0.0.1: Segmentation fault occurred at 000003e80000120e in /usr/sbin/apache2[apache2:4622] uid/euid:1000/1000 gid/egid:1000/1000, parent /usr/sbin/apache2[apache2:4286] uid/euid:0/0 gid/egid:0/0
grsec: Segmentation fault occurred at 000003e800001496 in /usr/sbin/apache2[apache2:5270] uid/euid:1000/1000 gid/egid:1000/1000, parent /usr/sbin/apache2[apache2:4286] uid/euid:0/0 gid/egid:0/0
```